# Add value to variable inside closure in swift

Tags: swift, closures

I am new to swift language and I have problem that I can't solve.

After running my app i get output of empty String: **nil**

So, my question is how to **add value to variable inside closure**?

Because when I add line inside closure ***print(self.latLong)*** I get output of coordinates, but I need that value inside of variable because I need to manipulate with that variable later in my code and I don't want to write all functionality inside that closure

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase

var latLong: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    findCordiante(adress: "Cupertino, California, U.S.")
    print(latLong)
}

func findCordiante(adress:String){

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(adress) {
        placemarks, error in

        if (placemarks != nil){
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
            let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude

            self.latLong = String(describing: lat!) + "," + String(describing: lon!)

        }else{
            //handle no adress
             self.latLong = ""
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift closure async order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880506/swift-closure-async-order-of-execution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that  `geocodeAddressString` runs asynchronously (i.e. it takes so long they have written it to return immediately and call its closure later, when the request is done), so `viewDidLoad` is printing `latLong` well before this property was eventually set in the `geocodeAddressString` completion handler closure.

The solution is to adopt asynchronous programming pattern in your own code. For example, employ your own completion handler pattern:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    findCordiante(adress: "Cupertino, California, U.S.") { string in
        // use `string` here ...

        if let string = string {
            self.latLong = string
            print(string)
        } else {
            print("not found")
        }
    }

    // ... but not here, because the above runs asynchronously and it has not yet been set 
}

func findCordiante(adress:String, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(adress) { placemarks, error in
        if let location = placemarks?.first?.location, location.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 {
            completionHandler("\(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latLong is `nil` because `print(latLong)` is called immediately after the view is loaded, before the value of `latLong` is set. You can define a function to handle the `latLong` and call it in the closure.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase

var latLong: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    findCordiante(adress: "Cupertino, California, U.S.")
    print(latLong)
}

func findCordiante(adress:String){

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(adress) {
        placemarks, error in

        if (placemarks != nil){
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
            let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude

            self.latLong = String(describing: lat!) + "," + String(describing: lon!)
            //Do something with latLong now 
            self.doSomething(withlatLong: self.latLong)

        }else{
            //handle no adress
            self.latLong = ""
        }
    }

}

private func doSomething(withlatLong latLong:String) {
    //Do whatever you want with latLong 
    print(latLong)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i need to save coordinates in variable. How can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean `save coordinates in variable`?  `self.latLong` will be set after `geocodeAddressString` finish in your code. If you want to be notified when `self.layLong` is set, you can use `didSet` or `willSet`