# Firebase Firestore global variable for async function

Tags: swift, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, global-variables

I want to set a global variable equal to some values I am fetching from my firestore database. However, I think that because this is a

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(self.id).getDocument { (snapshot, err) in

                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else{

                    self.nameGlobal = snapshot?.get("name") as! String ?? "failed"
                    self.usernameGlobal = snapshot?.get("username") as! String ?? "failed"

                }

            }
```

`print (self.nameGlobal)`
`print (self.usernameGlobal)`

Due to the async nature, the print statements at the end seem to be executed before the Firestore function is finished running. Does anyone know how I could force the function to finish updating the global variables before the subsequent lines are executed? I would really like to be able to access these variables outside of the callback rather than writing all my code inside of the callback.

Comment: Put the subsequent lines in the callback itself.  Or put them in another function that's called in the callback.

Comment: But is there any way to take the variable out of the callback and store it in a global variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390656/how-to-return-value-from-alamofire)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift closure async order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880506/swift-closure-async-order-of-execution)

Comment: You can store it in a global.  You just can't use it before the callback completes.

Comment: Is there a way to only execute the following lines after the callback completes?