# Parsing Alamofire JSON

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am building an app that will work with Plaid. Plaid provides a nice little LinkKit that I need to use to grab my `link_token`. I provide that `link_token` to authenticate to a bank. I have written a request using Alamofire to send the `.post` to get the new `link_token` when someone would want to add another account. My issue is when I decode the JSON to a struct that I have built I cant seem to use that stored `link_token` value.

Code to retrieve `link_token`

```
let parameters = PlaidAPIKeys(client_id: K.plaidCreds.client_id,
                              secret: K.plaidCreds.secret,
                              client_name: K.plaidCreds.client_name,
                              language: K.plaidCreds.language,
                              country_codes: [K.plaidCreds.country_codes],
                              user: [K.plaidCreds.client_user_id: K.plaidCreds.unique_user_id],
                              products: [K.plaidCreds.products])

func getLinkToken() {
    
    let linkTokenRequest = AF.request(K.plaidCreds.plaidLinkTokenURL,
                                      method: .post,
                                      parameters: parameters,
                                      encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseDecodable(of: GeneratedLinkToken.self) { response in
                                        print(response)
                                    }
                                    }
```

Struct I have built:

```
struct GeneratedLinkToken: Decodable {
    let expiration: String
    let linkToken: String
    let requestID: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case expiration = "expiration"
       case linkToken = "link_token"
       case requestID = "request_id"
    }
}
```

I have tested by calling the function `getLinkToken()` when pressing my add account or dummy button, I do get the data back that I am needing. Why wouldnt I be able to access `GeneratedLinkToken.linkToken` directly after the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't able to access `linkToken` property like this: `GeneratedLinkToken.linkToken`, because `linkToken` is as instance property([read here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/whats-the-difference-between-a-static-variable-and-a-class-variable))

If you want to get an instance after your request, you can do it like this:

```
func getLinkToken(completion: @escaping ((GeneratedLinkToken) -> Void)) {
    let linkTokenRequest = AF.request(K.plaidCreds.plaidLinkTokenURL,
                                      method: .post,
                                      parameters: parameters,
                                      encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseDecodable(of: GeneratedLinkToken.self) { response in
                                        print(response)

                                        // if response is an object of type GeneratedLinkToken
                                        switch response.result {
                                        case .success(let object):
                                            completion(object)                                             
                                        case .failure(let error):
                                             // hanlde error
                                        }
                                    }
}
```

Later you can call as:

```
getLinkToken { linkObject in
    print("My tokne: \(linkObject.linkToken)")
}
```

I added `completion`([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401439/how-could-i-create-a-function-with-a-completion-handler-in-swift)) to your method, since the request executing async, you can take a look at this Q/A: [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880506/swift-closure-async-order-of-execution). I also suggest you, pass `parameters` as a parameter to this function, not declare it globally.

Comment: This makes a bit more sense. I thought I would need a completion but was unsure how to structure.

Running this I get an error though:
`Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<GeneratedLinkToken, AFError>' to expected argument type 'GeneratedLinkToken'`

Comment: @thetanis I edited my answer, should work now

Comment: Alright, I get that switch statement now. I guess where I am failing from here is grasping how I assign that string value from
`getLinkToken { linkObject in.....` 
to something else. That print returns the right value. I've tried assigning an empty value to a variable and then adding that value in to it. 

```
let test = getLinkToken { object in
            var test1 = ""
            test1 = object.linkToken
            print(test1)
        }
```
but this isn't available to use outside this scope.

Sorry, still learning here.

Comment: @thetanis This looks like a different question, try to solve it yourself if you can't, just create another question, don't mix questions in question.